# how can i close Bootstrap Datepicker on double click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

```js
$(function(){      
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
      $(document).on("dblclick", ".datepicker td.day", function (e) {
        document.querySelector("#log").innerText += "triggered !\n"
    });
});
 document.querySelector("#log").innerText += "dblclick Logs here"
```

```css
.datepicker{
  cursor :pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="log"></div>
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

The dblclick event shows on in the chrome event listeners,for some reason does not fire.There is also no dblclick event in the [documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html).  Could somebody please give me a direction. As I would like to close the datepicker on double click.

Comment: Your problem is easy to replicate, I looked into their code to find what is happening, it seems like they are stopping event propagation on the day click.
I have also tried event capturing on Body  `var bodyEle = $("body").get(0);
if(bodyEle.addEventListener){
   bodyEle.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){console.log("ty")}, true);
}` but it is not happening on day click, it is very strange.
I am just curious why do you need double click?

Comment: @Harshkurra thank you , I need to close the  dropdown on double click, while letting the user select on single click without closing.